# How to set Jeditable Text maxlength?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, input, textbox, jeditable

I am trying to set the maxlength on Textbox on JEditable Datatable.
I have 10 different columns off which 6 are Editable Columns. and each maxlength is different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried maxlength like this. But it didn't work.

```
 type: 'text',
 onblur: 'submit',
 maxlength: 2,
 event: 'dblclick',
```

Comment: Did you see this? http://blogpad-online.blogspot.se/2010/10/jeditable-maxlength_12.html

Answer (score 3):

I was also searching for same and I found it from here [jEditable](http://blogpad-online.blogspot.se/2010/10/jeditable-maxlength_12.html)

Where you have to add one line in jquery.jeditable.js file as suggested in blog. Although I am writing here for reference

You have to add this line

```
if (settings.maxlength) { input.attr('maxlength', settings.maxlength); }
```

just after

```
if (settings.height != 'none') { input.height(settings.height); }
```

and then have to add

```
$('.loremipsum').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
    ...
    maxlength: 20,
    ...
});
```

wherever you have used jeditable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a similar thing for the Textarea fields.

```
                textarea: {
            element : function(settings, original) {
                var textarea = $('<textarea />');
                if (settings.maxlength) {
                    textarea.attr('maxlength', settings.maxlength);
                }
                else if (settings.rows) {
                    textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
                } else if (settings.height != "none") {
                    textarea.height(settings.height);
                }
                if (settings.cols) {
                    textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
                } else if (settings.width != "none") {
                    textarea.width(settings.width);
                }
                $(this).append(textarea);
                return(textarea);
            }
        },
```

I just added the initial if clause and made the original if clause an "else if"